# msedgedriver keeps crashing due to profile sign-in [javascript, selenium]

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, microsoft-edge

I use a school laptop for some Node.js stuff, and it is managed by an admin. This means that Microsoft Edge requires a profile to sign in.

Whenever I use msedgedriver with selenium, it asks me to sign in to a profile. After I sign in, the program crashes. This is (probably) because when signing in to a profile, msedge exits and re-opens. However, selenium thinks that msedge has crashed, and aborts the program.

Some console output:

```html
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62272/devtools/browser/33d28eb3-2603-4805-90a8-299c965c6f15
[22904:21196:0209/213152.746:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(123)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
[22904:19500:0209/213155.110:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(251)] START: GetDefaultBrowser(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[22904:21196:0209/213155.134:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [21:31:55.134] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[22904:19500:0209/213155.161:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(255)] END: GetDefaultBrowser()
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does the version of webdriver you are using match the version of Edge? Have you tried to use specific profile with argument `user-data-dir`? And can you describe your problem in more detail? Such as the version of selenium used, the version of Edge, the code sample that reproduces the problem? This will help solve the problem, thank you for your understanding.

Comment: The version of Edge matches the version of webdriver. I am using version 98.0.1108.43. The code used is below: `const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver"),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until,
    Keys = webdriver.Key;`

Comment: It looks like some of the code you provided is not complete, I'm afraid I can't reproduce your problem with it, what version of `selenium-webdriver` are you currently using, and does this problem occur on a specific site? It would be helpful if you could provide complete code that reproduces this issue.